# build linux apps with gtk# 2.0 using MonoDevelop

Tags: linux, monodevelop, gtk#

I created an app with gtk# 2.0 using MonoDevelop.

It works great in Debug mode, so i wanted to build a release.

But the release is always an *.exe file. How can i build it for Linux, so that i can use the app under linux?

Comment: What's wrong with .exe output? With Mono you can run it on Linux.

Comment: @Lex Li how? Cause i need it to autorun when Linux starts.

Comment: `mono some.exe` is the command to launch the executable. If you want the app to auto run, then check the documentation of your Linux distribution on where you should register the command.